# How to correctly link a Postgres database to an Oracle one?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a Oracle database with 20 users (schemas). Those schemas are knitted together through synonyms and foreign keys. Now, I would like to take a part of the data (one user) into a postgreSQL database. 
I can make a database link from postgreSQL to Oracle (and from Oracle to PostgreSQL) to solve a part of the problems but how do I solve to foreign keys problems (foreign key between postgreSQL and Oracle). What is the best way to go ?

Comment: I have not yet implemented the link. I was thinking of a db link. I am trying  to find a solution to make it possible and to initiate the first step a total migration from Oracle towards postgreSQL

Comment: Why do you need to link data from different schemas?

Comment: I am going to have a postgreSQL database with some animal related data. The rest of the data, owners, users and so one will stay in the Oracle database. Are you suggesting that I should duplicated the data ?

Comment: I think if you are separating schemas into different database systems (for whatever reason), you should just consider them as separate database and forget about the keys between them.

Comment: That make sense, it would reduce the dependency, and simplify most of the operations.

Comment: Well you may not need to duplicate all data, but one option would be to create e.g. a row (animal) in the Oracle database for each row (animal) the postgreSQL, to keep the key integrity. You can synchronize the rows (animals) between postgreSQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Approach (this is not about creating a specific link between Oracle and PostgreSQL, but how to avoid it):

Consider the Oracle and PostgreSQL databases as separate database. That is, no key relations between the the two database systems.

Any data that need to be referenced by both databases (such as the animals) **can**(*) be represented in both databases to keep the key relations and data integrity intact. You do not need to duplicate all data, but you can make sure all rows are present. Synchronize the shared data (animals) between the two systems.

Example:

PostgreSQL database:

```
Animals: [id, name, bio, blobs, etc.]
```

Oracle database:

```
Animals: [id, name]
Owners: [id, name]
AnimalOwners: [ownerId, animalId]
```

Typically, you want to manage the Animal data from one leading database, in this case I assume PostgreSQL. Each time you update an Animal row in PostgreSQL, copy the changes (if relevant) to the Animal table in Oracle.

(*) You could also forget about the keys and explicitly check for the existence of the required rows in the other database when creating the associatons. Also, you should be careful not to get rid of (types of) animals that are/were owned at some time.

Comment: That's interesting. I like the idea of not creating link at all because it preserve the independance of the PostgreSQL database. This is also true that I have to choose my point of view : choose my leading database.